# Python 3 - non-copying stream interface to bytearray?

Tags: python, stream, python-3.x, arrays

I read buffer of data from somewhere to `bytearray`. Now, I want to work with this data using stream-like interface (i.e. `read`, `seek` etc.)

Can I just wrap my `bytearray` with `io.BytesIO`?

```
mybytearray = bytearray(...)
stream = io.BytesIO(mybytearray)
```

My fear here is `BytesIO` copies data of `mybytearray`, but I don't want it - since buffer is very big. I don't want copies, I want the stream to work on original data and can modify it too. What can be done?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`BytesIO` manages its own memory and will copy a buffer used to initialize it. You could encapsulate your `bytearray` in a file-like class. Or you can go the other way, letting the `BytesIO` object handle memory allocation. Then you can get a view of the buffer that can be modified by index and slice, but you can't re-size the buffer while the view exists:

```
>>> f = io.BytesIO(b'abc')
>>> view = f.getbuffer()

>>> view[:] = b'def'
>>> f.getvalue()
b'def'

>>> view[3] = b'g'
IndexError: index out of bounds

>>> f.seek(0, 2)
>>> f.write(b'g')
BufferError: Existing exports of data: object cannot be re-sized

>>> del view
>>> f.write(b'g')
>>> f.getvalue()
b'defg'
```

---

Edit:

See [issue 22003](http://bugs.python.org/issue22003), `BytesIO` copy-on-write. The latest patch (cow6) supports copy-on-write for `bytes` only.